# jquery - Clear modal content without hiding the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

qI'm trying to clear the content that is in the modal body without actually closing the modal box. The new quote button would, in theory, change the quote. As I have it now all it does is continue to add a quote underneath.

Through my searching all of the way I have seen this answered say to close the box and use .removeData() or etc.

Below is the code for the modal box.

```
<div class="modal in" id="journalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Quotes for Life</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="text">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button onclick="quoteClick()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Here is the script I'm using to pull the api

```
function apiGrab(){
 $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&    filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback= function(a) {
  $(".modal-body").append(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this in youe quoteclick function

```
function quoteClick()
{ 
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
}
```

this will clear old content from dialog and further process going on

Comment: This won't work. A modal box isn't treated like a text area, which is where this would work. I just decided to change it to work in a text box instead of a modal box as it seems that you can't refresh the content on a modal box.